# Numbers that are the sum of 2 distinct nonzero squares in exactly 1 way

Tags: sequences-and-series, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

Is there a formula that says if a number is the sum of 2 distinct nonzero squares ?

This is the sequence I'm trying to emulate: 5, 10, 13, 17, etc..

http://oeis.org/A004431 (Invalid it contains **85**, etc..)

Need to make a program out of it, thanks in advance

I'm new here, sorry if the tags are somewhat lacking

EDIT: So this wasnt still the sequence I wanted. It must be the **Numbers that are the sum of 2 distinct nonzero squares in exactly 1 way**. So my previous question didn't specify the exactly 1 way part.

**http://oeis.org/A025302 (This is the one!)**

Comment: Possibly relevant is the Sum of Two-Squares theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem

Comment: The theorem in question is that a number $n$ is sum of two squares if and only if: (if $p$ is an odd prime divisor of $n$, then either $p$ appears to an even power in $n$, or $p\equiv1\pmod4$.) So, $90=2\cdot3^2\cdot5=9+81$. I believe that you’ll find that every $2^{2k+1}$ is necessarily the sum of two *equal* squares. This may be enough for you to answer your question.

Comment: @Lubin Yep that was it but I have one more specification. It can only have one way. Please see my edited question

Comment: Well, think of $65=5\cdot13=1+64=49+16$. Two primes, two ways. I think there’s a multiplicative number-theoretic function that may be a key to this, but I don’t have time to think the matter over.

Comment: @Lubin So I did the program with the rules you said. The numbers **325,425,650,725,845,850,925** popped to me as _warnings_. The sequence in http://oeis.org/A025302 ends in the number 226, so I don't know If they indeed belong to the sequence. Can you confirm me this ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Crossposted at: https://mathoverflow.net/q/321350/85967

Comment: Awfully sorry, I have a bad cold, and what brain-power I have is devoted to another problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t mean to be giving you a *rule*—I was just suggesting phenomena you might look at. I think I found the “multiplicative number-theoretic function” I was referring to, but it doesn’t quite measure the phenomena you’re specifying. Would you like me to write it up in an answer?

Comment: Yes ofc, it's my original question, so it still might be of use to some people. In the mean time, I discovered that this sequence is not the one I was looking for. As I said in the comments above, I found 7 numbers that don't belong to the  oeis.org/A025302 .. OESIS also doesn't figure out what my sequence is. For more information on my sequence it's coming from this problem https://projecteuler.net/problem=611

Comment: @Lubin If you have some extra time, and want to know how my sequence is being built, check out that link above. Anyways, just post your answer to the problem since it might help some other folks. Thanks for your work